# Specify which socket ip address to recv from when using multiple sockets

Tags: python, sockets

I am using sockets to talk between multiple devices, each with their own IP address (think one hub to many devices). I want the hub to be able to recv from a specific device's sockets using that device's IP address.

I have thought about using the `recvfrom()` function but this only tells you the origin IP *after* you have already read from the buffer. I want to be able to specify this before hand.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Do you want to ignore all packets except those sent from a specific IP address? And these are, what, UDP sockets?

Answer (score 2):

Use `connect()`. Although UDP is technically connectionless, the sockets API allows you to create pseudo-connections this way. Calling `connect()` on a UDP socket makes it only receive from the specified remote IP and port.

This also allows you to use `send()` rather than `sendto()` with that socket; it will use the connected IP and port as the destination automatically.

See [Connecting UDP Sockets](https://erlerobotics.gitbooks.io/erle-robotics-python-gitbook-free/udp_and_tcp/connecting_udp_sockets.html) to read more details about this.